# What does 九洚 mean?

Tags: meaning, character-identification

My friend asked me about the character in this picture:
[image: ???]
He said it's a map, and that part looks like a lake with rivers as its branches, so he thought it's a lake name. I've tried to search it in Google but found nothing of those two characters combined. Using Google Translate, the closest is 九洚 read as Jiǔ Jiàng (said Google Translate), but searching for Jiǔ Jiàng only resulted in other character read the same. Anyone knows what is that? Any lake with that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://zidian.eduu.com/detail/6907.html

It pronounces féng.

浲

```
部首：氵部
拼音：féng
注音：ㄈㄥ
笔画：10笔
郑码：vrCI
四角号码：   37154
笔顺编号：4413541112
```

基本字义
浲
féng
古同“漨”，水名。

浲
hóng
大水。

笔画数：10；
部首：氵；
笔顺编号：4413541112

Comment: This is! This is the right character! Judging from the picture, I realized I got the wrong character, but that's the closest character I got from the stroke I made in Google Translate (I even used my graphic tablet to make it). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**九泽**

**zdic**:

> 1.九州的湖泊。《书·禹贡》：“九川涤源，九泽既陂。” 孔颖达 疏：“九泽，九州之泽。”
>
> 2.特指北方的湖泊。《淮南子·时则训》：“北方之极，自九泽穷夏晦之极，北至令正之谷。” 高诱 注：“九泽，北方之泽。夏，大也。晦，暝也。”
>
> 3.古代的九大湖泊。《周礼·夏官·职方氏》泽、薮并称，其名称及位置如下： 扬州 ： 具区 ； 荆州 ： 云梦 ； 豫州 ： 圃田 ； 青州 ： 望诸 ； 袞州 ： 犬野 ； 雍州 ： 弦蒲 ； 幽州 ： 貕养 ； 翼州 ： 杨纡 ； 并州 ： 昭馀祁 。
>
> 4.泛称深渊湖泊。 晋 王齐之 《萨陀波仑赞》：“龙潜九泽，文明未接。” 宋 曾巩 《一鹗》诗：“势疑空山竭九泽，杀气已应太白高。”

Apparently refers to a bunch of different lakes or types of lakes, take your pick.

Grand Ricci says

> (Géogr. hist.) Jiu ze : autre nom 昭余祈 Zhao yu qi, marécage qui était situé au sud-ouest du district de 祈 Qi, au 山东 Shan dong.

Another name for 昭余祈 swamp in Qi, Shandong.